# Does LLVM IR has scope for duplicated variable name?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm new to LLVM, does LLVM IR has scope for duplicated variable name ?

For example:

```
@x = global i32 0


define void @hello() {
  %x = alloca i32, align 4
}
```

Does `@x` variable name duplicates with `%x` ?

Answer (score 2):

Had you try to write a code that do something with these variables, you'd find that the answer is **NO**.

To access `@x` you'll have to use `Module::GetGlobalVariable` method, which obviously wouldn't pick up `%x`. Similarly, to access `%x`, you'd have to iterate a `Function`s `BasicBlocks`, looking for an `Instruction` named "x". Yes, the `%x` thing is not a variable, but an instruction.

Finally, at the textual IR level these values also can't be mixed in any way, because global values in LLVM are prefixed with `@` while local ones - with `%`.